# jquery multiple selectors including 'this' - best clean syntax

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, this

So I know you can use multiple selectors like so

```
$("#div_1 , #div_2").doStuff......
```

But

I want to select 'this' (based on a rollover function) and another element on the page.

I have tried a number of things and cant seem to get it to work.

```
$("this , #div_2").doStuff......//not working // 
$(this ", #div_2").doStuff......//not working // 
$(this" #div_2").doStuff......//not working //
```

Seems easy but still cant get it to work.

Thanks in advance

S

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use the [add()](http://api.jquery.com/add/) method:

```
$(this).add("#div_2").doStuff();
```

Comment: woah -  answer in uner 2mins - and viewed 11 time gotta love SO - Thanks for the answer!